# Spring application fails on PostgeSQL connection: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

Please help me to fix the problem, I've checked all similar questions but didn't find the correct answer.

**Log:**

```
2022-10-26 12:40:04.091  INFO 12152 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-10-26 12:40:04.135 ERROR 12152 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/shaded/com/ongres/scram/client/ScramClient$ChannelBinding
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at com.example.homepharmacy.HomePharmacyApplication.main(HomePharmacyApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/shaded/com/ongres/scram/client/ScramClient$ChannelBinding
    at org.postgresql.jre8.sasl.ScramAuthenticator.processServerMechanismsAndInit(ScramAuthenticator.java:74) ~[postgresql-42.2.0.jar:42.2.0]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:621) ~[postgresql-42.2.0.jar:42.2.0]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207) ~[postgresql-42.2.0.jar:42.2.0]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.0.jar:42.2.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.0.jar:42.2.0]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452) ~[postgresql-42.2.0.jar:42.2.0]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254) ~[postgresql-42.2.0.jar:42.2.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.client.ScramClient$ChannelBinding
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 53 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Application class:**

```
package com.example.homepharmacy;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HomePharmacyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HomePharmacyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class PharmacyService {

    private final PharmacyRepository pharmacyRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PharmacyService(PharmacyRepository pharmacyRepository) {
        this.pharmacyRepository = pharmacyRepository;
    }

    public Drug findDrugById(Long id) {
        return pharmacyRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() ->
                        new DrugNotFoundException("Drug not found by id = " + id));
    }

    public Drug save(Drug drug) {
        return pharmacyRepository.save(drug);
    }

    public void deleteDrugById(Long id) {
        pharmacyRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

**Repo:**

```
@Repository
public interface PharmacyRepository extends CrudRepository<Drug, Long> {

    List<Drug> findAllByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
public class PharmacyController {

    private final PharmacyRepository pharmacyRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PharmacyController(PharmacyRepository pharmacyRepository) {
        this.pharmacyRepository = pharmacyRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/drug/new")
    public ReturnId postDrug(@RequestBody @Valid Drug drug) {
        pharmacyRepository.save(drug);
        return new ReturnId(drug.getId());
    }
}
```

**entity:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "drugs")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Drug {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "manufacturer")
    private String manufacturer;

    @Column(name = "pharmaceutical_form")
    private String pharmaceuticalForm;

    @Column(name = "dosage")
    private String dosage;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private String quantity;

    @Column(name = "units_of_measure")
    private String unitsOfMeasure;

    @Column(name = "expired_date")
    private LocalDate expiredDate;
}
```

**build.gradle dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres (also was /home-pharmacy)
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL15Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
```

DB structure:

[image]

I think the problem is with the connection to DB. May be I'm using wrong URL, but I've tried to change a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with gradle but I'm guessing the version of `org.postgresql:postgresql` you specified is incompatible.

If you have a look at your dependency tree you may find multiple versions are being pulled in under sub dependencies or you might just need to bump `org.postgresql:postgresql` to a newer version.